# Object of type ElementNSImpl coming as com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl

Tags: java, xml, soap, ws-trust

So my WS-Trust server deployed on JDK1.8.0_161 environment is expecting a request which will contain xml nodes of type `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl`, but when the request comes, the nodes are of type `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl`, which is not making me not read the data from request. I am using `xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0` library, but wondering if JDK is messing up with the request parsing on server end. Currently I only see `rt.jar` that contains `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl`. What am I missing? Have anyone seen this error?

Comment: [yogsma] It seems you make ws-trust work with Java. Could you share your knowledge? :)

Comment: @mzy - I have number of posts on my blog betterjavacode.com for WS-Trust.

Comment: I found only one article https://betterjavacode.com/category/apache-cxf. Do I search in right category?

Comment: Send me email from the website. Website is currently going through maintenance, so you are not seeing all search results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `Element` as interface rather than using implementation `ElementNSImpl`. This will make the implementation environment independent.

So the code looks like this

```
if(object instanceof org.w3c.dom.Element)
```

instead of

```
if(object instanceof ElementNSImpl)
```